# For Facebook webhook updates, how long does it normally take for a page post to be relayed by a webhook to a callback URL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm troubleshooting [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358911) with a Node application I've inherited serving as a webhook callback endpoint.

To debug, I'm posting messages to a page that has been subscribed by the Facebook app associated with the endpoint and following my Node app's log.

After several hours, I still see no update requests from Facebook for my page posts.

Comparing timestamps on posts to my app's logs for the last update requests it received (several days ago), I see that it appears that there was about an 8 hour lag between the post and the update request.

I've searched [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#callback) for help but could only find this:

> Update notifications are aggregated and sent in a batch of up to 1000 updates.
>
> If any update sent to your server fails, we will retry immediately, then try a few more times with decreasing frequency over the next 24 hours. Your server should handle deduplication in these cases. Updates unaccepted for 24 hours will be dropped.

This gives me the impression that updates are not instantaneous. But are several hour delays the norm?

Can anybody with more experience with Graph API webhooks provide a ballpark for normal lag?

Comment: Did you figured it out? I am also not sure how exactly this works

Comment: Never figured this out (I would have posted answer). I am no longer working on the project that prompted it.